# Parsing XML by position using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have some XML from a third party that looks something like this:

```
<Breakfasts>
    <Name>Cornflakes</Name>
    <Description>Just add milk</Name>
    <Name>Toast</Name>
    <Name>Muesli</Name>
    <Description>Healthy option</Description>
</Breakfasts>
```

We have to infer the relationship between Name and Description by the position of the nodes in the XML.  So Cornflakes is "Just add milk", Toast does not have a description, Muesli is "Healthy option" and so on.

I have a class called Breakfast which looks like this:

```
public class Breakfast
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

How can this XML be parsed (using XDocument, perhaps?) into a List of Breakfast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ick - what a horrible format. I'd probably do something like:

```
var list = doc.Descendants("Name").Select(MakeBreakfast).ToList();
...

static Breakfast MakeBreakfast(XElement nameElement)
{
    string name = (string) nameElement;
    var nextElement = nameElement.ElementsAfterSelf().FirstOrDefault();
    string description = 
        nextElement != null && nextElement.Name.LocalName == "Description"
        ? (string) nextElement
        : null;
    return new Breakfast { Name = name, Description = description };
}
```

Comment: "MakeBreakfast" awesome name

Answer (score -1):

This is what I'd do:

```
var breakfasts =
    doc.Root.Elements("Name").Select(x => new Breakfast()
    {
        Name = x.Value,
        Description = 
            x.NextNode as XElement != null 
            ? (x.NextNode as XElement).Name == "Description"
                ? (x.NextNode as XElement).Value 
                : ""
            : "",
    }).ToList();
```

This gives me:

[image: breakfasts]

Comment: Note that `NextNode` may return a text node - that's why I used `ElementsAfterSelf` instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Won't `x.NextNode as XElement != null` cover off on the next node being a text node?

Comment: It means than if there's `<Name>Foo</Name>Ignore me<Description>Bar</Bar>` you'll Ignore the description.